# Accessing one class variable from another class in C++

Tags: c++, class

Suppose I'm in some function of class A, in this function I define an object of class B, say b, and call some function using b.func() which updates some values and arrays, say x and A. Then, I create an object of another class C, say c, and call one of its function using c.func(). This function is supposed to use x and A that were updated in the class B during the call b.func(). 
How can I access them within the function c.func()? I tried to define an object of class B in c.func(), but the values of x and A appear to be empty...

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot about function parameters.

Bearing that I smell something bad to you design because your three classes seems to much tighten here is one thing you can do.

Since B know A and c, when calling c.func() define and call c.func(A a, X x).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have created two completely separate objects of class B.

You created the first object within a function, and then initialized it.  Then you created a new object of class B in a different function.  There's no reason it should have the same values.

You need to start thinking about the scope of your objects - where they are created and initialized, and how they get passed to where they are needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inheritance concept.

In C++, inheritance is a process in which one object acquires all the properties and behaviors of its parent object automatically. In such way, you can reuse, extend or modify the attributes and behaviors which are defined in other class.

so, inherit class c from class b so class c acquires all method and property of class B.

refer following site for inheritance.

https://www.javatpoint.com/cpp-inheritance

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_inheritance.htm